# "Live search" using Hotwire/Turbo Frames resulting in "Content Missing" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

I'm using the following setup to do a "live search" with turbo frames.

```
# index.html.erb
<%= form_with(url: tools_path, method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: :tools }) do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :query, placeholder: "Search tools...", oninput: "this.form.requestSubmit()" %>
<% end %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag :tools do %>
  <ul role="list">
    <%= render partial: "tool", collection: @tools %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

```rb
# tools_controller.rb
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @tools = current_user.tools.search(params[:query]).distinct
  else
    @tools = current_user.tools.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
end
```

```rb
# tool.rb

scope :search, -> (query) do
  return if query.blank?

  joins(:categories).where("tools.name ILIKE :query OR brand ILIKE :query OR notes ILIKE :query OR part_number ILIKE :query OR categories.name ILIKE :query", query: "%#{query}%")
end
```

It works wonderfully when there are results, but if there aren't any, it shows a "Content Missing" error in the browser.

```html
<turbo-frame id="tools" src="https://localhost:3000/tools?query=pressure+washer" complete="">
  <strong class="turbo-frame-error">Content missing</strong>
</turbo-frame>
```

I've tried adding a check for `@tools.empty?` inside the `turbo_frame_tag` but it seems to have no effect.

Not sure what else to do to debug this.

Running Rails 7.1.0.alpha along with turbo-rails 1.4.0.

Comment: What does the console say?

Answer (score 0):

The "Content Missing" error usually shows up if Turbo is unable to find the turbo frame which initiated the request in the response. Based on your code, I think the problem is that the `turbo_frame_tag` is not being rendered when there are no results.

To fix this, you can try the following:

Add a `data-turbo-if="@tools.any?"` attribute to the `turbo_frame_tag`. This will tell Turbo to only render the frame if there are any results.
Inside the `turbo_frame_tag`, add a `<div class="empty-state">No tools found</div>` element. This will be displayed if there are no results.
Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
<turbo_frame_tag :tools data-turbo-if="@tools.any?">
  <ul role="list">
    <%= render partial: "tool", collection: @tools %>
  </ul>
</turbo_frame_tag>

<turbo_frame_tag :tools data-turbo-if="@tools.empty?">
  <div class="empty-state">No tools found</div>
</turbo_frame_tag>
```